# Display Android Toast message after file has copied

Tags: android, toast

I am fairly new to Android development so I thought I would start off with a basic app. When a button is pressed, it copies a file to the location written in the code (see my code below). When I press the install button and the file is copied to its location, I want a toast message to display "Successfully Installed or Error while copying file". How would I implement this?

```
public class TrialActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        runDialog(5);
    }

    private void runDialog(final int seconds)
        {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait...", "unpacking patch in progress");

            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View paramView)
                        {

                        }

                        {

                            InputStream in = null;
                            OutputStream out = null;
                            String filename="savegame.bin";
                            try {

                                in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.savegame);
                                out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Android/data/files/" + filename);
                                copyFile(in, out);
                                in.close();
                                in = null;
                                out.flush();
                                out.close();
                                out = null;
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                                Message message = Message.obtain();
                                message.what = 1;  // success message
                                mHandler.sendMessage(message);


                            }

                        }
                    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int read;
                        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
                            out.write(buffer, 0, read);

                        }
                    }
                }
                );
        }



    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage( Message msg )
                {
                    Toast toast;
                    switch(msg.what)
                    {
                    case 1: // for success
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Created By MRxBIGxSTUFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        break;
                    case 0: // for Error
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error... Application has shutdown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
        };
}
```

Comment: far as i can see, you are only sending a message to the handler in case of an exception

Comment: sorry my bad didn't mean to include the handler bit, I have tried a few different codes that i have found online but to no success, What code would i use to catch whether the file has copied or not?

Comment: @user1305471 so you are using the code without understanding what it is doing in the first place? It will make you troubles sooner or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use AsyncTask to run your process in background. Which doesn't freeze the User Interface event the copying file size goes big.

You can show your progressbar while loading the operation.

```
public class CopyFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{  
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

} 
@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
 }

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

{ 
      //Post Execute
       dialog.cancel();
      //Use toast here to toast the message
      //Check condition toast message
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Created By MRxBIGxSTUFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

  // Your operation..Dont Edit Any Views here

    return null;
}
}
```

I think this is one of the best way to handle with files(i.e copying,downloading etc)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To show the Toast you have to make it and display it yourself. Like this:

```
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Read more on Toasts [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

And your code is buggy as you hardcoded `/sdcard/` which is **WRONG**. Use [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)